# I want to be able to toggle the background color of the two divs with a button click

Tags: javascript

I can't get the backgroundColorRed and backgroundColorBlue to properly toggle the div's background using the specified button. Is there any way to only change the div's background color with the click of a button, the two should be able to be red and blue at the same time if their buttons were clicked. I want to use the css to change the color, that's why I included the two background styles in the css.

```js
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var backgroundColorRed = function(){
    var div1Background = document.getElementById("div1");
 var changeRed = document.getElementById("divButton1");
    
    changeRed.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.body.classList.toggle("backgroundColorRed");   
    })
}

var backgroundColorBlue = function(){
    var div1Background = document.getElementById("div2");
 var changeRed = document.getElementById("divButton2");
    
    changeRed.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.body.classList.toggle("backgroundColorBlue");   
    })
}
window.onload = function(){
 $("divButton1").onclick = backgroundColorRed;
    $("divButton2").onclick = backgroundColorBlue;
}
```

```css
.backgroundColorRed{
 background-color: red;
}

.backgroundColorBlue{
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <section id="section1">
   <div id="div1">
    <h2>Div One</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis magni reprehenderit quibusdam ipsam eius odit iste consequatur necessitatibus voluptatibus deserunt maxime esse, similique, cupiditate facere quis quos id delectus est.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="div2">
    <h2>Div Two</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem magni voluptatibus tempore aut corrupti, ducimus optio consequuntur. Quasi debitis a dicta natus voluptas alias ea, quis excepturi ut, eius accusantium.</p>
   </div>
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
   <button type="button" id="divButton1">Div1 Red</button>
   <button type="button" id="divButton2">Div2 Blue</button>
 </section>

 </main>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your issue?

```js
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

window.onload = function() {
  $("divButton1").addEventListener('click', function() {
    $("div1").classList.toggle("backgroundColorRed");
  })

  $("divButton2").addEventListener('click', function() {
    $("div2").classList.toggle("backgroundColorBlue");
  })
}
```

```css
.backgroundColorRed {
  background-color: red;
}

.backgroundColorBlue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="section1">
    <div id="div1">
      <h2>Div One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis magni reprehenderit quibusdam ipsam eius odit iste consequatur necessitatibus voluptatibus deserunt maxime esse, similique, cupiditate facere quis quos id delectus est.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      <h2>Div Two</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem magni voluptatibus tempore aut corrupti, ducimus optio consequuntur. Quasi debitis a dicta natus voluptas alias ea, quis excepturi ut, eius accusantium.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
    <button type="button" id="divButton1">Div1 Red</button>
    <button type="button" id="divButton2">Div2 Blue</button>
  </section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `addEventListener` is only needed once:

```js
const $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function backgroundColorRed() {
  $("div1").classList.toggle("backgroundColorRed");   
}

function backgroundColorBlue() {
  $("div2").classList.toggle("backgroundColorBlue");   
}

window.onload = function () {
  $("divButton1").addEventListener("click", backgroundColorRed);
  $("divButton2").addEventListener("click", backgroundColorBlue);
}
```

```css
.backgroundColorRed{
  background-color: red;
}

.backgroundColorBlue{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section id="section1">
        <div id="div1">
          <h2>Div One</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis magni reprehenderit quibusdam ipsam eius odit iste consequatur necessitatibus voluptatibus deserunt maxime esse, similique, cupiditate facere quis quos id delectus est.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
          <h2>Div Two</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem magni voluptatibus tempore aut corrupti, ducimus optio consequuntur. Quasi debitis a dicta natus voluptas alias ea, quis excepturi ut, eius accusantium.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="section2">
        <button type="button" id="divButton1">Div1 Red</button>
        <button type="button" id="divButton2">Div2 Blue</button>
      </section>

    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```